# Using type() with Annotations in python

Tags: python, types, annotations, metaprogramming

I am trying to learn how to use annotations.

I have this class:

```
class ApiItemPydanticWithTags(ApiItemPydantic):
    tags: str
ApiItemPydanticWithTags.__name__ = "ApiWIthTags"
```

I want to replicate this class creation with type():

```
ApiItemPydanticWithTags = type("ApiWIthTags", (ApiItemPydantic,), dict(tags: str = None))
```

But Obviously, `dict(tags: str = None)` does not work ...

Comment: What is the *purpose* of these annotations? What are you trying to accomplish with them?

Comment: building an api with FastAPI using Tortoise-orm as ORM and Pydantic as data validation and serialization.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what I wanted to do with:

```
ApiItemPydanticWithTags = type(
    "ApiWIthTags", (ApiItemPydantic,), dict(__annotations__={"tags": str})
)
```